# Command line failed with error code 8 in phonegap/cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ant

Hello friends i want to teach phonegap-cordova as follow step of `http://phonegap.com/install/` and when i fire command `$ phonegap run android` in command prompt i get `Command line failed with error code 8` error in command prompt. my cordova lib placed at `C:\Users\MAC\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\lib` address and WinAnt is in `C:\Users\MAC\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\lib\WinAnt` address which thing i forgot please help me quickly,thanks in advance.